# How to determine if Python is running inside a virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Is it possible to determine if the current script is running inside a virtualenv environment?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to know that?

Comment: i.e. to be able to write custom script that generates prompt for your shell and you want that prompt to indicate if you are in venv or not, so you want to be able to detect that from within that code, best w/o calling external tools.

Comment: Accepted answer didn't work for me (2020, python3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04)
This answer worked:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580137/1296044

Comment: Keep It Simple: (in Jupyter Notebook or Python 3.7.1 terminal on Windows 10)


```import sys
print(sys.executable)```

# example output: >> `C:\Anaconda3\envs\quantecon\python.exe`

OR 
```sys.base_prefix```

# Example output: >> 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\quantecon'

Comment: A potential time saver is going to ask _why_ you need to find out how python is running. Rather than attempting to figure out how python is running after the fact, if your problem can be solved by understanding _how_ python will be invoked before it happens, the solution becomes easy and much more universal. In that case, it becomes MrHetii's simple answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28388115/881411. i.e. if you control invoking python and you can check via shell prior to invoking for the presence of `${VIRTUAL_ENV}`, then you will know whether python will be running in a venv or not.

Comment: One reason:  You may wish to set $HOME to be somewhere else when executing in virtualenv.  You could put your application dot-files into the venv directory to avoid a tug-of-war with a non-venv version.

Comment: If it is more important what kind of environment you are in, you can use command `pip list`. Name of venv shall not matter (same for no venv), rather versions of used packages, right?

Answer (score 354, accepted):

The reliable and documented way is to compare [`sys.prefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix) and [`sys.base_prefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.base_prefix). If they're equal, you're not in a virtual environment, otherwise you are. Inside a venv, `sys.prefix` points to the directory of the virtual environment, and `sys.base_prefix` to the Python interpreter used to create the environment.

This is documented under [*How venvs work*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#how-venvs-work):

> It is sufficient to check `sys.prefix != sys.base_prefix` to determine if the current interpreter is running from a virtual environment.

This works for Python stdlib [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and for [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) (since version 20):

```
def in_venv():
    return sys.prefix != sys.base_prefix
```

Older versions of `virtualenv` used `sys.real_prefix` instead of `sys.base_prefix`, and `sys.real_prefix` did not exist outside a virtual environment. In Python 3.3 and earlier `sys.base_prefix` did not ever exist. So a check that also handles some legacy cases could look like this:

```
import sys


def get_base_prefix_compat():
    """Get base/real prefix, or sys.prefix if there is none."""
    return (
        getattr(sys, "base_prefix", None)
        or getattr(sys, "real_prefix", None)
        or sys.prefix
    )


def in_virtualenv():
    return sys.prefix != get_base_prefix_compat()
```

*Using the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable is not reliable*. It is set by the virtualenv `activate` shell script, but a virtualenv can be used without activation by directly running an executable from the virtualenv's `bin/` (or `Scripts`) directory, in which case `$VIRTUAL_ENV` will not be set. Or a non-virtualenv Python binary can be executed directly while a virtualenv is activated in the shell, in which case `$VIRTUAL_ENV` may be set in a Python process that is not actually running in that virtualenv.

Comment: If you are using virtualenv (github.com/pypa/virtualenv), this answer is equally correct for Python 2 or Python 3. If you are using pyvenv (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/), a virtualenv-equivalent built into Python 3.3+ (but not the same thing as virtualenv), then it uses sys.base_prefix instead of sys.real_prefix, and sys.base_prefix always exists; outside a pyvenv it is equal to sys.prefix.

Comment: I've been using this successfully in Windows 8/8.1 editions to discern whether the program runs inside a virtualenv or not but on Windows Server 2012 R2 this returns False regardless if the program runs inside a virtualenv or not! :(

Comment: @Kounavi I don't think it's likely that the Windows version would have any impact. This answer is a core part of how virtualenv works on any platform. Is it possible you are using Python 3 pyvenv, not virtualenv, on the Windows 2012 machine? Or that something is going on with the PATH and you are not in fact running in the virtualenv when you think you are?

Comment: @CarlMeyer I'm using Python 2.7.9 x64. The only modules I have installed are pip (7.0.3), setuptools (7.0), vboxapi (1.0), virtualenv (13.0.3) and virtualenvwrapper-powershell (12.7.8). I'm looking at it to see why this happens :)

Comment: Also, inside the virtualenv this returns False (tried it manually in a bunch of machines hell even in Surface Pro 3). Nothing suspicious, as far as my PATH is concerned.

Comment: @CarlMeyer Ok, I resolved it. Something was going on with my Python installation. I removed it and installed everything from the start (although the vboxapi needs to be installed again :P). I don't know if this has to do with a corrupted installation or the fact that wheel now comes along with pip (=>7). Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Also, using Anaconda/Miniconda environments does not work either :/

Comment: One-liner for bash scripts `PYTHON_ENV=$(python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('1') if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix') else sys.stdout.write('0')")`

Comment: I am using Anaconda's Python 2.7 Environment. No matter if I am using the root environment or virtual environment, sys.real_prefix is not found.

Comment: @SamMyers: for bash scripts is much easier to directly use `$VIRTUAL_ENV`

Comment: **This answer is obsolete,** unsurprisingly. Specifically, this answer returns false negatives for common use cases. That's bad. Instead, see either: [hroncok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839451/hroncok)'s [authoritative update correctly detecting all non-Anaconda venvs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580137/2809027) or [Victoria Stuart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1904943/victoria-stuart)'s [authoritative answer correctly detecting all Anaconda venvs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40099080/2809027). (*All my upvotes for whoever combines those two answers.*)

Comment: @CarlMeyer  Please consider updating the answer, since it's accepted and pinned to the top. **It doesn't work with stdlib python3 `venv`**.

Comment: Updated the answer to account for stdlib `venv` module and changes in latest `virtualenv`.

Comment: This method will return false positives (in venv) when running through the `ipython` REPL since the `sys.prefix` will be something like `/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec` which is never the same as the base prefix.

Comment: @domjancik That sounds like a Fruitbox problem. When I run `ipython3` from the command line (sans venv) in Fedora 36, `sys.prefix` and `sys.base_prefix` are both `/usr`, and `sys.executable` is `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: In shell python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix == sys.base_prefix)", it will print True, if virtual env is not activated and False, if it is activated.

Answer (score 299):

Try using `pip -V` (notice capital V)

If you are running the virtual env. it'll show the path to the env.'s location.

Comment: If you've moved your `virtualenv` around a lot, it's possible this can fail or lie to you. If it's lying, you can do `find /path/to/venv/ -type f -exec sed -ie "s:/old/path/to/venv:/path/to/venv:g" {} \+`. If it's failing (I got "bad marshal data") you'll need to wipe the .pyc files with `find /path/to/venv -type f -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \+` (don't worry, they'll rebuild automatically).

Comment: I just tested this on Windows 10 with Python 3.7. 
It prints the location of pip from the default install `...\lib\site-packages` in the `%PATH%`.  So it will return a false positive in that case.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18 with pip 21.0.1, `pip -V` returns path of user installation of pip, if not in a venv. Therefore, this doesn't tell you if a venv is activated or not.

Comment: This might not work if you're using ZSH and you configured the prompt to display something else

Comment: Works on Windows 10 if you are inside an env.

Comment: The question is how to determine it from python script, not a command line.

Comment: It shows the path to the site-packages, which doesn't tell you whether it's a venv or not. It also requires a pip installation in the site, which is not a given (pip is a third-party app, it's not stdlib and not guaranteed to be there). You could make an alt-install with "venv" in the path name, or you could make a venv at a system-looking path, so this answer is a heuristic at best.

Answer (score 101):

Check the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable.

The `$VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable contains the virtual environment's directory when in an active virtual environment.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
'/some/path/project/venv'
```

Once you run `deactivate` / leave the virtual environment, the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` variable will be cleared/empty. Python will raise a `KeyError` because the environment variable was unset.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'VIRTUAL_ENV'
```

These same environment variable checks can of course also be done outside of the Python script, in the shell.

Comment: This works both for a `virtualenv` virtualenv and a `venv` virtualenv.

Comment: @verboze: as it is supposed to do, right? A deactivated virtualenv means the user script is _not_ running on one.

Comment: This checks if a virtualenv is activated, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the Python process running is from that virtualenv.

Comment: This answer can be wrong in both directions. A Python process can be running in a virtual environment by direct execution of the virtualenv's Python binary (or a script with that binary as its shebang), without ever shell "activating" the virtualenv. In that case this answer will give a false negative. Alternatively, even with a virtualenv activated in the shell, a non-virtualenv Python binary or script could be directly executed, and this answer would give a false positive.

Comment: It could be useful for edge use cases, like for instance if you want to test if the virtualenv is activated before running Python code from another language. In my case, my Node server spawns Python services here and there, and I want to check if the virtual env is activated before running Jest test.

Answer (score 100):

This is an improvement of the accepted answer by [Carl Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3207/carl-meyer). It works with [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for Python 3 and 2 and also for the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module in Python 3:

```
import sys


def is_venv():
    return (hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix') or
            (hasattr(sys, 'base_prefix') and sys.base_prefix != sys.prefix))
```

The check for `sys.real_prefix` covers virtualenv, the equality of non-empty `sys.base_prefix` with `sys.prefix` covers venv.

Consider a script that uses the function like this:

```
if is_venv():
    print('inside virtualenv or venv')
else:
    print('outside virtualenv or venv')
```

And the following invocation:

```
$ python2 test.py 
outside virtualenv or venv

$ python3 test.py 
outside virtualenv or venv

$ python2 -m virtualenv virtualenv2
...
$ . virtualenv2/bin/activate
(virtualenv2) $ python test.py 
inside virtualenv or venv
(virtualenv2) $ deactivate

$ python3 -m virtualenv virtualenv3
...
$ . virtualenv3/bin/activate
(virtualenv3) $ python test.py 
inside virtualenv or venv
(virtualenv3) $ deactivate 

$ python3 -m venv venv3
$ . venv3/bin/activate
(venv3) $ python test.py 
inside virtualenv or venv
(venv3) $ deactivate
```

Comment: Since Python 3.3 is no longer maintained or supported by most Python 3 frameworks and applications, this function now reduces to a trivial one-liner: `def is_venv(): return hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix') or sys.base_prefix != sys.prefix`. *Just sayin'.*

Comment: Sadly this doesn't appear to work with `pipenv` created virtual environments.

Comment: Works with classic venv and pipenv too (both through `pipenv run` and `pipenv shell`) for me (MacOS Ventura on Mac M1, Python 3.9.10)

Answer (score 58):

There are multiple good answers here, and some less robust ones.
Here's an overview.

## How not to do it

Do not rely on on the location of Python or the `site-packages` folder.

If these are set to non-standard locations, that does *not* mean
you're actually in a virtual environment.  Users can have more than one
Python version installed, and those are not always where you expect them to be.

Avoid looking at:

- `sys.executable`
- `sys.prefix`
- `pip -V`
- `which python`

Also, do not check for the presence of `venv`, `.venv` or `envs` in any of these paths.
This will break for environments with a more unique location. For example,
[Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) uses hash values as the name for its environments.

## `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable

Both `virtualenv` and `venv` set the environment variable `$VIRTUAL_ENV` when activating an environment.
See [PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#specification).

You can read out this variable in shell scripts, or use this Python code to determine if it's set.

```
import os
running_in_virtualenv = "VIRTUAL_ENV" in os.environ

# alternative ways to write this, also supporting the case where
# the variable is set but contains an empty string to indicate
# 'not in a virtual environment':
running_in_virtualenv = bool(os.environ.get("VIRTUAL_ENV"))
running_in_virtualenv = bool(os.getenv("VIRTUAL_ENV"))
```

The problem is, this only works when the environment is *activated* by the `activate` shell script.

You can start the environment's scripts *without activating the environment*, so if that is a concern, you have to use a different method.

## `sys.base_prefix`

`virtualenv`, `venv` and `pyvenv` point `sys.prefix` to the Python installed inside of the virtualenv as you would expect.

At the same time, the *original* value of `sys.prefix` is also made available as `sys.base_prefix`.

We can use that to detect if we're in a virtualenv.

```
import sys
# note: Python versions before 3.3 don't have sys.base_prefix
# if you're not in virtual environment
running_in_virtualenv = sys.prefix != sys.base_prefix
```

## Fallback: `sys.real_prefix`

Now watch out, `virtualenv` before version 20 did not set `sys.base_prefix` but it set `sys.real_prefix` instead.

So to be safe, check both as suggested in [hroncok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580137/1075152):

```
import sys

real_prefix = getattr(sys, "real_prefix", None)
base_prefix = getattr(sys, "base_prefix", sys.prefix)

running_in_virtualenv = (base_prefix or real_prefix) != sys.prefix
```

## Anaconda

If you're using Anaconda virtual environments, check
[Victoria Stuart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40099080/1075152).

Comment: The OP is asking "How do I?", not "How NOT to?"  This answer is overkill.  It goes beyond the spirit of the question and obfuscates the answer with too many variations.  Please keep your answers as simple as possible and answer the question directly.

Comment: I am summarizing the multiple answers here, and providing advice on which one might be right for specific circumstances.  The original question does not provide enough context to select one of these techniques as the 'best' one -- it just isn't that simple.

Comment: In the section for sys.base_prefix, shouldn't the test be: `running_in_virtualenv = sys.*base_*prefix != sys.prefix`

Comment: Thank you, @florisia!  I am in process of transitioning from virtualenvwrapper to the built-in venv for application deployment, and your explanation gave me the template on how to do it.  I had been relying only on the `if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):` test, which no longer worked.

Comment: I understand the objection about what "Not" to do. A simple edit would be to start with the best answer and then specify why other methods are not acceptable. However, in the end, this provided me with the best, correct details.

Comment: What is the objection to looking at `sys.prefix`? Seems like it's possible to be effectively running in a virtual env without `VIRTUAL_ENV` set, e.g. by doing `/Users/me/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/python3 script.py`. In this case, `sys.prefix` or or `sys.exec_prefix` seems to be the best way to discern (though I'm not sure how you would tell if it is venv-like, I guess by looking at `sys.path`)

Comment: @DeusXMachina `sys.prefix` by itself does not tell you if that Python is a virtualenv or not.

Comment: @florisla Roger. It's necessary, but not sufficient, because `prefix` could be pointing to a prefix path that isn't a virtualenv. How does one then tell if `prefix` is indeed a virtualenv? I've seen counter-examples where `VIRTUAL_ENV` is not set, e.g. poetry envs.

Comment: @DeusXMachina By comparing `sys.prefix` to `sys.base_prefix`.

Comment: @florisla That is what I am asking. I thought `sys.prefix != sys.base_prefix` only suggests, but does not confirm, you are operating inside a virtualenv (or rather, any isolated env)? Basically, is an isolated env the only thing that can change `sys.prefix` to something other than `sys.base_prefix`? That *seems* to be what the docs suggest. But the python path system is zany, so I want to be 100% sure. Also I'm talking `python>=3.3`.

Answer (score 29):

According to the virtualenv pep at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#specification you can just use `sys.prefix` instead `os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']`.

the `sys.real_prefix` does not exist in my virtualenv and same with `sys.base_prefix`.

Comment: virtualenv is the standalone project that works on any Python version (https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv). The PEP you linked to is for pyvenv, which is based on virtualenv but is implemented differently (better) and is built-in to Python 3.3+. This question is about virtualenv, not pyvenv. You're correct that in a pyvenv there is no ``sys.real_prefix``.

Comment: A nice way to detect from bash using this answer is to run:

    `env |grep VIRTUAL_ENV |wc -l`

which will return a 1 if in a venv or a 0 if not.

Comment: If you're in a shell you can simply use `[[ -n $VIRTUAL_ENV ]] && echo virtualenv` or `[[ -z $VIRTUAL_ENV ]] && echo not virtualenv` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 15):

To check whether your inside Virtualenv:

```
import os

if os.getenv('VIRTUAL_ENV'):
    print('Using Virtualenv')
else:
    print('Not using Virtualenv')
```

You can also get more data on your environment:

```
import sys
import os

print(f'Python Executable: {sys.executable}')
print(f'Python Version: {sys.version}')
print(f'Virtualenv: {os.getenv("VIRTUAL_ENV")}')
```

Comment: This is the best cross-platform (Windows/Unix) approach.

Comment: So far, this is only cross platform, python 2 and python 3 compatible way. Thanks.

Comment: Works on Mac too (MacOS Ventura on Mac M1, Python 3.9.10)

Comment: This works ONLY if the venv had been ACTIVATED! If it hasn't it works nowhere.

Answer (score 9):

- *Updated Nov 2019 (appended).*

---

I routinely use several Anaconda-installed virtual environments (venv).  This code snippet/examples enables you to determine whether or not you are in a venv (or your system environment), and to also require a specific venv for your script.

**Add to Python script (code snippet):**

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Want script to run in Python 3.5 (has required installed OpenCV, imutils, ... packages):
import os

# First, see if we are in a conda venv { py27: Python 2.7 | py35: Python 3.5 | tf: TensorFlow | thee : Theano }
try:
   os.environ["CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV"]
except KeyError:
   print("\tPlease set the py35 { p3 | Python 3.5 } environment!\n")
   exit()

# If we are in a conda venv, require the p3 venv:
if os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV'] != "py35":
    print("\tPlease set the py35 { p3 | Python 3.5 } environment!\n")
    exit()

# See also:
# Python: Determine if running inside virtualenv
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/python-determine-if-running-inside-virtualenv  
# [ ... SNIP! ... ]
```

**Example:**

```
$ p2
  [Anaconda Python 2.7 venv (source activate py27)]

(py27) $ python  webcam_.py
    Please set the py35 { p3 | Python 3.5 } environment!

(py27) $ p3
  [Anaconda Python 3.5 venv (source activate py35)]

(py35) $ python  webcam.py -n50

    current env: py35
    processing (live): found 2 faces and 4 eyes in this frame
    threaded OpenCV implementation
    num_frames: 50
    webcam -- approx. FPS: 18.59
    Found 2 faces and 4 eyes!
(py35) $
```

**Update 1 -- use in bash scripts:**

You can also use this approach in bash scripts (e.g., those that must run in a specific virtual environment).  Example (added to bash script):

```
if [ $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV ]        ## << note the spaces (important in BASH)!
    then
        printf 'venv: operating in tf-env, proceed ...'
    else
        printf 'Note: must run this script in tf-env venv'
        exit
fi
```

**Update 2 [Nov 2019]**

- For simplicity, I like Matt's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245168/1904943).

Since my original post I've moved on from Anaconda venv (and Python itself has evolved *viz-a-viz* virtual environments).

Reexamining this issue, here is some updated Python code that you can insert to test that you are operating in a specific Python virtual environment (venv).

```
import os, re
try:
    if re.search('py37', os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']):
        pass
except KeyError:
    print("\n\tPlease set the Python3 venv [alias: p3]!\n")
    exit()
```

Here is some explanatory code.

```
[victoria@victoria ~]$ date; python --version
  Thu 14 Nov 2019 11:27:02 AM PST
  Python 3.8.0

[victoria@victoria ~]$ python
  Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 23 2019, 18:51:26) 
  [GCC 9.2.0] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import os, re

>>> re.search('py37', os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'])
<re.Match object; span=(20, 24), match='py37'>

>>> try:
...     if re.search('py37', os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']):
...       print('\n\tOperating in Python3 venv, please proceed!  :-)')
... except KeyError:
...     print("\n\tPlease set the Python3 venv [alias: p3]!\n")
... 

    Please set the Python3 venv [alias: p3]!

>>> [Ctrl-d]
  now exiting EditableBufferInteractiveConsole...

[victoria@victoria ~]$ p3
  [Python 3.7 venv (source activate py37)]

(py37) [victoria@victoria ~]$ python --version
  Python 3.8.0

(py37) [victoria@victoria ~]$ env | grep -i virtual
  VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/victoria/venv/py37

(py37) [victoria@victoria ~]$ python
  Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 23 2019, 18:51:26) 
  [GCC 9.2.0] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import os, re
>>> try:
...     if re.search('py37', os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']):
...       print('\n\tOperating in Python3 venv, please proceed!  :-)')
... except KeyError:
...     print("\n\tPlease set the Python3 venv [alias: p3]!\n")
... 

    Operating in Python3 venv, please proceed!  :-)
>>>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do `which python` and see if its pointing to the one in virtual env.

Comment: `which` is not available by default on Windows.  You could use `where` instead on Windows, or employ [whichcraft](https://pypi.org/project/whichcraft/).  Or look at `sys.executable`.  But still, there are better methods.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way is to just run: `which python`, if you are in a virtualenv it will point to its python instead of the global one

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question (which is concerned about the "current script").  However this answers my particular question, "how do I find out if I'm in a virtual environment from the command line."

Answer (score 2):

You can look for the 'signature' of whatever venv method you're trying to support.  In my case I want to support:

```
python -m venv venv_dir
```

or

```
virtualenv venv_dir
```

So I can write:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

IS_VENV_ENVIRONMENT = (Path(sys.prefix) / "pyvenv.cfg").exists()
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

"Running this command creates the target directory (creating any parent directories that don’t exist already) and places a pyvenv.cfg file in it"

NB:  virtualenv also creates the same file but I couldn't see any docs about that, I only noticed by experiment.

Answer (score 1):

(edited) I found that way, what do you think of it ? (it also returns the venv base path and works even for **readthedocs** where checking the **env** variable does not):

```
import os
import sys
from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_vars


def get_venv_basedir():
    """Returns the base directory of the virtualenv, useful to read configuration and plugins"""

    exec_prefix = get_config_vars()['exec_prefix']

    if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix') is False or exec_prefix.startswith(sys.real_prefix):
        raise EnvironmentError('You must be in a virtual environment')

    return os.path.abspath(get_config_vars()['exec_prefix'] + '/../')
```

Answer (score -1):

In windows OS you see something like this:

```
C:\Users\yourusername\virtualEnvName\Scripts>activate
(virtualEnvName) C:\Users\yourusername\virtualEnvName\Scripts>
```

Parentheses mean that you are actually in the virtual environment called "virtualEnvName".

Comment: You and I can read 'virtualEnvName' just fine.  But the question is, how a Python module can read this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to directly check if you are in a virtualenv the above answers are the correct solutions.

However, if the real problem you are trying to solve is determining whether you can `pip install` a dependency without erroring (something that would be true if you were in a virtualenv), you can simply check if you have write permissions for the location of the Python executable:

```
os.access(sys.executable, os.W_OK)
```

This works in all versions of Python, and also returns `True` if you run the system Python with `sudo`. Here's an example of how this would be useful:

```
import os, sys
can_install_pip_packages = os.access(sys.executable, os.W_OK)

if can_install_pip_packages:
    import pip
    pip.main(['install', 'mypackage'])
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of great methods posted here already, but just adding one more:

```
import site
site.getsitepackages()
```

tells you where `pip` installed the packages.

Comment: This does not tell if the Python is running inside a virtual environment or not.

Comment: @florisla Could you elaborate? If `site.getsitepackages()` outputs a directory that's not the system one, then you can deduce you're in a virtual environment.

Comment: You can install Python in multiple locations. For example, on Windows you can install a 'system' Python and a WinPython distribution plus a Conda-based Python.  These all have different site-packages folders but are not necessarily created by (or used in) a `virtualenv`.

Comment: @florisla Good point - I just saw this (venv or not) is what the question is asking (I had written a similar answer for another question). I agree this might not give the surefire answer as to whether you're in a venv or not, but could help in telling you which Python or which `venv` you're using.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Anaconda here is the solution. This command lists all the discoverable environments

```
conda info --envs
```

Answer (score -1):

I typically use a bash wrapper script to start my application and was running into the problem of imports not working because of pip packages not being installed outside the virtual environment.

Using the solution provided by Matt Harasymczuk, here are the few lines of bash script to check the virtual environment has been activated before starting the application.

```
#!/bin/bash

# check the virtual environment is active
if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]
then
    echo "[ERROR] Virtual environment not activated"
    exit 1
fi

# start the application
python3   # amend with application name and other details

# end of file
```

Answer (score -1):

As not already mentioned, and time has moved on since this question was made, I thought I'd mention pyenv-virtualenv.

**pyenv** allows multiple python interpreters to exist on the same system at the same time without collision.  The interpreter can automatically change when you chdir into a given path. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

**pyenv-virtualenv** is a pyenv plugin that, like venv/pipenv, creates independent virtualenvs each with different module configurations, but now that env also specifies which interpreter(s) can be used. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

If you are using pyenv or pyenv-virtualenv then this one line bash command will work.

```bash
test -x $(which pyenv) && { pyenv which python | grep -q "^$(pyenv root)"; } && echo "1"
```

This could be used to set an environment variable that Python can read via one of the hook scripts that pyenv uses, or updated via the shell prompt hook variable, $PROMPT_COMMAND. (Note: shell hook example may need some speedup shortcuts/tricks or risk being annoying)

e.g. Here IN_VENV is either 'system' or a version number or a virtualenv

```bash
export IN_VENV=$(test -x $(which pyenv) && { pyenv which python | grep -q "^$(pyenv root)"; } && pyenv version-name)
```

If you need to detect this inside Python with no help from the os, then

```
from subprocess import run

# run cmd in shell
# return None if error else stdout or ""
def sh(cmd, **kw):
    res = run(cmd, capture_output=True, shell=True, **kw)
    return None if res.returncode != 0 else res.stdout.decode("ascii").strip()

pyenv = sh("which pyenv")
assert pyenv is not None, "No pyenv command"
assert sh(f"test -x {pyenv}") is not None, "pyenv is non-exe"
pycmd = sh(f"pyenv which python")
assert pycmd is not None, "no pyenv python"
root = sh(f"{pyenv} root")
assert root is not None, "'pyenv root' did not run"
in_pyenv = sh(f"grep -q ^{root}", input=pycmd.encode('utf-8') is not None
```

This not only finds the virtualenv but proves it is working.

Answer (score -2):

It's not bullet-proof but for UNIX environments simple test like

```
if run("which python3").find("venv") == -1:
    # something when not executed from venv
```

works great for me. It's simpler then testing existing of some attribute and, anyway, you should name your venv directory `venv`.