# How can a shell function know if it is running within a virtualenv?

Tags: python, bash, shell, virtualenv

How should a `bash` function test whether it is running inside a Python virtualenv?

The two approaches that come to mind are:

```
[[ "$(type -t deactivate)" != function ]]; INVENV=$?
```

or

```
[[ "x$(which python)" != "x$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python" ]]; INVENV=$?
```

(Note: wanting `$INVENV` to be 1 if we're inside a virtualenv, and 0 otherwise, is what forces the backward-looking tests above.)

Is there something less hacky?

Comment: There is also `command -v`, a shell built-in.

Comment: Answer that actually works in 2020 (python>=3.6):  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580137/1296044

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, I just found a similar question, from which one can easily derive an answer to this one:

[Python: Determine if running inside virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549)

E.g., a shell script can use something like

```
python -c 'import sys; print (sys.real_prefix)' 2>/dev/null && INVENV=1 || INVENV=0
```

(Thanks to Christian Long for showing how to make this solution work with Python 3 also.)

EDIT: Here's a more direct (hence clearer and cleaner) solution (taking a cue from JuanPablo's comment):

```
INVENV=$(python -c 'import sys; print ("1" if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix") else "0")')
```

Comment: a optional command for check : `python -c 'import sys; print hasattr(sys, "real_prefix")' `

Comment: Add parentheses to support Python 3 `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.real_prefix)' 2>/dev/null && INVENV=1 || INVENV=0`

Comment: My python env (`python3 -m venv venv`) does not have the `sys.real_prefix` attribute.  Would this be ok as an alternative?  `INVENV=$( python -c 'import sys ; print( 0 if sys.prefix == sys.base_prefix else 1 )' )`

Comment: @BrendanSimon looks fine to me.

Comment: Works when run directly on the terminal, doesn't appear to be working from inside a bash script (running inside a venv)!

Comment: You can also cast it to `int()` instead of the if statement: `INVENV=$(python3 -c 'import sys; print(int(hasattr(sys, "real_prefix")))')`

However, running from a simple bash script I could not get confirmation that the script is using the venv. The answer below using `$VIRTUAL_ENV` variable (set by sourcing the `activate` script) did.

Answer (score 67):

```
if [[ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "" ]]
then
  INVENV=1
else
  INVENV=0
fi
// or shorter if you like:
[[ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" == "" ]]; INVENV=$?
```

**EDIT**: as @ThiefMaster mentions in the comments, in certain conditions (for instance, when starting a new shell – perhaps in `tmux` or `screen` – from within an active virtualenv) this check may fail (however, starting new shells from within a virtualenv may cause other issues as well, I wouldn't recommend it).

Comment: I avoided this approach because I've had situations in which `$VIRTUAL_ENV` was set, but (for some reason), not in `$PATH`...

Comment: Not sure what `$PATH` has to do with it? Or do you mean you want to check if your current working directory is part of a virtualenv?

Comment: sorry for my confusing comment; if `$VIRTUAL_ENV` is not in `$PATH` then the `python` executable that gets used by everything else will not be the one in the virtualenv.  By itself, assigning a value to `$VIRTUAL_ENV` does nothing.

Comment: I agree, but my snippet doesn't assign to `$VIRTUAL_ENV`, it checks for it. When it exists, it means a virtual environment is active (that variable is set by the `activate` script and unset by `deactivate`). Which is what you wanted, right?

Comment: I found this particular solution valid and worked well for me. Exactly what I was after. Thanks! :)

Comment: This is not reliable. For example, in tmux sessions started while inside a virtualenv the venv is not active but $VIRTUAL_ENV is still set.

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention it in your answer that it can fail in some cases

Comment: Running inside a simple bash script, this answer worked for me (you can also echo the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` for debugging). The accepted answer did not work from inside a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

If you use virtualenvwrappers there are pre/post scripts that run that could set INVENV for you.

Or what I do, put the following in your your .bashrc, and make a file called .venv in your working directory (for django) so that the virtual env is automatically loaded when you cd into the directory

```
export PREVPWD=`pwd`
export PREVENV_PATH=

handle_virtualenv(){
    if [ "$PWD" != "$PREVPWD" ]; then
        PREVPWD="$PWD";
        if [ -n "$PREVENV_PATH" ]; then
            if [ "`echo "$PWD" | grep -c $PREVENV_PATH`" = "0"  ]; then
                deactivate
                unalias python 2> /dev/null
                PREVENV_PATH=
            fi
        fi

        # activate virtualenv dynamically
        if [ -e "$PWD/.venv" ] && [ "$PWD" != "$PREVENV_PATH" ]; then
            PREVENV_PATH="$PWD"
            workon `basename $PWD`
            if [ -e "manage.py" ]; then
                alias python='python manage.py shell_plus'
            fi
        fi
    fi
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=handle_virtualenv
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  BTW, I think that bash already maintains `OLDPWD`, which the same thing as `PREVPWD` in your code.