# Get virtualenv's bin folder path from script

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using virtualenvwrapper with a django project that has a management task that automatically writes some config files, so the user just has to

```
./manage.py generate_configuration > much_nice.conf
```

And then move the file elsewhere. One of the generated config files is a task for supervisord that launches a celery worker. The problem I'm getting is that I don't know how to **output the path of the celery executable** that is **within the bin folder** of the virtualenv. Essentially, I'd like to have the output of the command

```
which celery
```

One option is using `sys.executable`, get the folder (which seems to be the `bin` folder of the virtualenv) and that's it... but I'm not sure.

Doesn't virtualenv have any kind of method to get the path itself?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The path to the virtual env is in the environment variable VIRTUAL_ENV

```
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. I managed to get the value in python using `os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']`.

Comment: Note that `VIRTUAL_ENV` is set by the virtualenv's `activate` script, and it's possible to use the virtualenv python without activating the virtualenv. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1883251/1286571

Comment: Also, conda do not use this variable. This will beak for users using CONDA or any other ways to manage their python distributions. I don't think this is a robust approach. Using `sys.executable` as proposed by @laurent-laporte seems more reliable.

Answer (score 25):

The `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable is only available if the virtual environment is activated.

For instance:

```sh
$ python3 -m venv myapp
$ source myapp/bin/activate
(myapp) $ python  -c "import os; print(os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'])"
/path/to/virtualenv/myapp
```

If not activated, you have an exception:

```sh
(myapp) $ deactivate
$ myapp/bin/python -c "import os; print(os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'])"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/os.py", line 635, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'VIRTUAL_ENV'
```

IMO, you should use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) to get the path of your Python executable,
and then build the path to celery:

```py
import sys
import os

celery_name = {'linux': 'celery', 'win32': 'celery.exe'}[sys.platform]
celery_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), celery_name)
```

Answer (score 7):

How about referencing sys.prefix? It always outputs a result regardless of a virtualenv is activated or not, and also it's more convenient than getting grand parent position of sys.executable.

```
$ python -c 'import sys;print(sys.prefix)'
/usr
$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ python -c 'import sys;print(sys.prefix)'
path/to/venv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) to do such things from python

```
>>> from fabric.api import local
>>> local('which celery')
```

Comment: This will probably not work. A sub-shell started is not going to have the virtual env on $PATH so `which` won't work.