# virtualenv directory from script

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, pip, virtualenv

This used to work, but now both give the same result:

```
$ python -c 'from pip import __file__ as pip_loc; print pip_loc,'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.pyc
$ /tmp/.venv/bin/python -c 'from pip import __file__ as pip_loc; print pip_loc,'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.pyc
```

How do I get the `/tmp/.venv` path?

Comment: BTW: This one is just for `virtualenvwrapper`, `$VIRTUAL_ENV` is not defined with 'vanilla' `virtualenv`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22003769.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to nedbat on IRC:

```
$ python -c 'from sys import executable; print executable,'
/usr/bin/python
$ /tmp/.venv/bin/python -c 'from sys import executable; print executable,'
/tmp/.venv/bin/python
```

EDIT: Actually what I really wanted was `get_python_lib` of:

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Activate the virtualenv before importing pip.

Comment: That wouldn't work. To humour you: `/tmp$ . /tmp/.venv/bin/activate
(.venv) /tmp$ python -c 'from pip import __file__ as pip_loc; print pip_loc,'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.pyc`

Comment: Beats me. I can't reproduce that, second line from your initial question gives the venv - path here.

Comment: What version are you running? - Because this used to work for me also. - I'm running `Python 2.7.12+`

Comment: same version here.