# Linode/Django Can't see site when I runserver at ip:8000

Tags: django, ubuntu, mezzanine, linode

I had started a fresh linode running ubuntu 19.04 and the first time I used the directions at:

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-mezzanine-cms-on-ubuntu-18-04/

To install Mezzanine CMS it worked just fine, I could run the runserver command and see the django website. Eventually it started giving me a problem after trying 50 ways to deploy the site using apache and mod_wsgi.

I gave up and rebuilt the server and then still couldn't see the new install at the IP when I ran run server. I figured maybe it was because I accidentally installed some things using "python" and others with "python3" so I rebuilt the server.

This third time I followed the direction perfectly, the only difference is I didn't install a mysql server just kept the default SQLlite server and created a DB and Django Superuser.

- I have added my ip as a host in settings.py and local_settings.py
- I have already ran makemigrations and migrate
- I did check to see if maybe the IP had changed when I rebuilt, it hadn't
- My local environment on my laptop works fine, just not the linode

Any suggestions on anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment Guide

**Step 1 (Installation)**

- Install apache2 mod_wsgi
- Install virtualenv
- Install virtualenv
- Install Nginx for asynchronous event-driven approach to handle multiple client requests
- Install mysql

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

  sudo apt-get install virtualenv ufw

  sudo apt-get install nginx

  sudo apt-get install mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev

  sudo mysql_secure_installation

**Step 2 (Apache & Hostname & User)**

- Set hostname and add it into /etc/hosts with hostname and your Server IP
- Create new user and give add to the group sudo for safety

  sudo adduser username

  sudo usermod -aG sudo
- Enable SSH authentication for login & Edit default port of ssh in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074034/not-able-to-change-ssh-port-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts
- Edit /etc/apache2/site-availabledefault-000.conf for your new Django configuration

**Step 3 (Firewall)**

- sudo ufw allow 8000
- sudo ufw allow http
- sudo ufw allow ssh
- sudo ufw default allow outgoing
- sudo ufw default deny incoming
- Enable all other required port numbers
- ssh sudo ufw enable

**Step 4 (Django configuration)**

- Chown static and media forlders and edit it's permission recursively
- Add allowed host in settings.py
- Checkout deployment checklist in django official website and do it.

**Step 5 (Please checkout)**

- For apache configuration please visit https://pythonprogramming.net/deploying-to-server-django-tutorial/
- Edit the path given in your apache configuration (path for WSGI Script,python-path, python-home ) if any errors found like Internal server error, miss configuration etc
- For reference of python-home path please refer [Get virtualenv's bin folder path from script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003769/get-virtualenvs-bin-folder-path-from-script)
- You can also add python-path to WSGIDaemonProcess
- Additionally, you can visit puttygen for public and private key generation to login through SSH

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem turned out I just needed to suddenly bind dev server to 0.0.0.0

the command to do so was

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Rinshans answers is definetley the details for deployment, I've followed those steps just kept making some mistake in the config and wsgi scripts. I'm going to try deploying with Gunicorn or use the Fabric self-deployment tools built in to Mezzanine CMS, just haven't done so yet.