# Confirmation when installing with pip globally

Tags: python, bash, pip

Sometimes when working with Python projects one can forget to activate a virtual environment.

Is there a way to get an explicit confirmation when installing Python modules with pip to the global scope instead of a virtual environment?

Comment: Installing in the global scope shouldn't work unless you ran `pip` with `sudo`, which you shouldn't do if you're trying to work in a virtualenv.

Comment: @jwodder If you install Python through Mac OS X's Homebrew, everything is installed to `/usr/local/` and you could `pip install` "globally" without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wrap `pip install`, e.g.:

```
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
        # replace this with your confirmation callback
        print('Warning! installing in global scope!')
    install('argh')
```

Sources:

[Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950647/165753)

[Python: Determine if running inside virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883251/165753)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```bash
$ pip config set install.require-virtualenv true
```

but this results in a rather inconvenient error when trying to install without a virtual environment:

```
ERROR: Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

I have opened a [PR](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/11753) implementing a more user-friendly option (at least in my opinion) to enable a warning instead of an error that also has a prompt to ask whether you'd like to continue or not. If that gets merged then you'll be able to do the following:

```
$ pip config set install.global-install-warning true
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
WARNING: Could not find an activated virtualenv.
Proceed (y/N)?
```