# check virtualenv activation in makefile

Tags: makefile, devops

I am working on an app which has frontend (angularjs) and backend(python, flask framework). I am creating a `Makefile` for this app.

To install backend dependencies using `requirements.txt` file, I want to check if `virtualenv` has been activated or not.

If `virtualenv` is activated then only installs dependencies using `requirements.txt` file otherwise not.

dummy:

```
if virtualenv_activated:
   install_dependencies
```

I checked this [link: running inside virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/python-determine-if-running-inside-virtualenv) but didn't understand much about writing this in Makefile.

Any useful help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found out the way to do this, we can write it as:

```
ifeq ($(VIRTUAL_ENV), )
    @echo "virtual env is not activated"
else
    @echo "virtual env is activated"
endif
```

So, this way we can check for `virtual_env` activation.

Thanks!