# How to install python-gi without disabling conda?

Tags: python

```
redshift-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/redshift-gtk", line 26, in <module>
    from redshift_gtk.statusicon import run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redshift_gtk/statusicon.py", line 32, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

How can I install python3-gi library on Ubuntu 16.04 without disabling conda? There is conda package for gi as far as I could find. I have installed gi with apt-get but I think my path only searches conda packages.

Comment: Did you install it using `sudo apt-get install python3-gi`?

Comment: tried that and it installed but I think it's only looking at the conda path

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/python-determine-if-running-inside-virtualenv) thread, I'm not in a virtualenv

Comment: Maybe you need to try to use it? It will help you to avoid creating a library mess on your system. Maybe you have some conflicts connected with the libraries you have installed. Try to install virtualenv and work from there.

Comment: yeah, that's probably smarter than using conda without virtualenv. do you if I have to reinstall all the libraries I installed through conda? Also, how is virtualenv different from conda env?

Comment: Sorry I have never used conda. Need to look at this first.