# Where to store files generated by a python library

Tags: python, pip

I would like to know where I am allowed to store files from a python library I am working on.

The lib would download a public key once and then store it in order to cache it. Where should this file go?

Are there any conventions?

For example, JupyterLab uses a `share/` directory inside the current environment:
[image: Share folder example]

Comment: That doesn't really depend on Python, but on the operating system it runs on. Different systems have different conventions for different types of programs.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I would like to avoid storing it in a /tmp or something though, to have more control on the life cycle of the file. I've seen libs (like JupyterLab for instance) storing files in python's share/ folder, which would be OS agnostic. Do you know something about this folder ?

Comment: If it's a lib, it should let the programmers using it specify where they want files to be stored.

Comment: Why not, thanks for the suggestion. It's a library I'm working on for my job and I have control over the applications that will use it. A generic solution would avoid me the manual configuration on each app that use it but if there is no such thing I'll use this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different OSes have different conventions but a common hint is: for a library installed globally or locally for a user (`pip install --user`) store files in the user's home directory, in a directory under `$HOME` (or `%HOME%`), `$HOME/.cache/`, `$HOME/.local/share`. For a library installed into a virtualenv the directory must be in the virtualenv.

The library [`appdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) provides a portable way to find necessary directory.

```
pip install appdirs
```

You probably need `user_data_dir`.

Comment: Do you know how to make it aware that it's in a venv?

Comment: @MickeyDickey https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883251/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=determine+virtual+environment

Comment: thank you. I was wondering whether there was a way to make appdirs itself aware of this, rather than just generally make my program aware. Because appdirs just return normal system-wide (rather than venv) paths.

Comment: @MickeyDickey BTW `appdirs` was deprecated, the current project is https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/ They don't want to support virtual environments but provide [some hints](https://github.com/platformdirs/platformdirs/issues/129#issuecomment-1690784069).