# printing from bash if virtualenv is activated

Tags: bash, virtualenv

I want to print in the console if virtualenv is activated.

Given that activated environment is "myvirtualenv", code should be like this:

```
echo some_function
```

and result will be

```
myvirtualenv
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if Python is running inside virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/determine-if-python-is-running-inside-virtualenv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtualenv's activation script sets "VIRTUAL_ENV" environment variable. Just print it:

```
echo "$VIRTUAL_ENV"
```