# ImportError: No module named htmlcreator even though it is installed

Tags: python, apache2, python-module, geany

Python script (testbov.py) below extracts a sentence from the novel Madame Bovary.

'''

```
#!/usr/bin/env python       
from random import randint
import io
import codecs
from htmlcreator import HTMLDocument
import webbrowser

with codecs.open('./bovary_sc_no_susp.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as source: 
    data=source.read() 
    splot_data=data.split(".") 
    has = randint(0,len(splot_data)) 
    prise = splot_data[has] 

document = HTMLDocument()
document.set_title('a slice of Bovary')
document.add_header('The slice')
document.add_text(prise)
document.write('my_document.html')  
webbrowser.open('./my_document.html')
```

'''

The script when run from the directory where it is (/var/www/html/test/cgi-bin) by the following command 'python testbov.py' does what he has to do and shows the extracted sentence in a browser page.
(Python is python 3.7 installed by miniconda)

When script is launched from Geany using the run button it opens a terminal with the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testbov .py", line 7, in <module>
    from htmlcreator import HTMLDocument
ImportError: No module named htmlcreator

------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

When script is called through a browser pointing to localhost/test, index.html in test directory is below :

```
<html><head><title>minimal page</title></head>
<form action="http://localhost/test/cgi-bin/testbov.py" />
<input type="submit" value="Go !" />
</form></html>
```

I get error 500 with following message in /var/log/apache2/error.log :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/test/cgi-bin/testbov.py", line 7, in <module>
    from htmlcreator import HTMLDocument
ImportError: No module named htmlcreator
```

So it seems that neither browser nor geany are able to find htmlcreator (installed through pip) while terminal is able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

the correct import is

```
from html_creator import Document
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it runs in its own virtual environment. You need to install the module in that virtual env.
You can check it in your script.
[Determine if Python is running inside virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/determine-if-python-is-running-inside-virtualenv)

```
import sys

def is_venv():
    return (hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix') or
            (hasattr(sys, 'base_prefix') and sys.base_prefix != sys.prefix))

if is_venv():
    print('inside virtualenv or venv')
else:
    print('outside virtualenv or venv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this small debug code:

```py
import os
print(os.environ['_'])
```

at the beginning of your script to verify which python is used for executing the script in both scenarios.

And then make sure they're either exactly the same or `htmlcreator` is available in both environments.