# from apiclient import discovery ImportError: No module named apiclient

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apprtc

I am running [apprtc](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc) source code I found on github in windows 10. But I have this error when I look at the Cmd console. It seems like a **apiclient**  is missing. I installed it using `pip install` but I steel get the same error. I also tried `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client` but I still get the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 311, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\Projets\APPRTC\apprtc-master\src\app_engine\apprtc.py", line 23, in <module>
    import analytics
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\Projets\APPRTC\apprtc-master\src\app_engine\analytics.py", line 14, in <module>
    import apiauth
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\Projets\APPRTC\apprtc-master\src\app_engine\apiauth.py", line 12, in <module>
    from apiclient import discovery
ImportError: No module named apiclient
INFO     2020-07-11 00:59:21,395 module.py:865] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2020-07-10 23:59:21,443 wsgi.py:269]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 311, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\Projets\APPRTC\apprtc-master\src\app_engine\apprtc.py", line 23, in <module>
    import analytics
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\Projets\APPRTC\apprtc-master\src\app_engine\analytics.py", line 14, in <module>
INFO     2020-07-11 00:59:21,443 module.py:865] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    import apiauth
  File "C:\Users\Gilbert\Documents\Projets\APPRTC\apprtc-master\src\app_engine\apiauth.py", line 12, in <module>
    from apiclient import discovery
ImportError: No module named apiclient
```

Comment: Try creating `anaconda` or `virtualenv` and installing the packages and running the apps

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but I still get the save error, I created a virtual environment, I installed all the packages and when I run the code I got the save problem

Comment: After creating virtualenv, check whether python is pointing to the virtualenv python

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/determine-if-python-is-running-inside-virtualenv - this should work

Comment: I also installed the packages in virtualenv ...no errors encountered

Comment: if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix') returns false

Comment: And `pip -V ` is returning `pip 19.2.3 from c:\users\gilbert\documents\projets\apprtc\apprtc-master\env\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: Using Python 3 is not supported: `The dev_appserver tool does not support development of Python 3 apps on Windows.` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command

Answer (score 0):

I think your sample code is outdated, the correct way to import the discovery service by using the Google Api client in App Engine is like this code snippet.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# this will take the credentials that was defined by the command 'gcloud auth application-default login' on local environments, this is already defined on App Engine STD/Flex(no custom runtime) and Cloud functions.

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()


# if you are using Cloud functions or App Engine (GAE) STD environment set
# cache_discovery=False, to avoid try to save cache on disk
# if this is not set, the application works fine but will thrown some warnings

service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)

# this example is to use cloud resource manager, but you can change this for the service that you need
#disable warnings to avoid noise in the logs, this applies for GAE STD & Cloud functions

logging.getLogger('googleapiclient.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
google-api-python-client==1.9.3
oauth2client==4.1.3
```

[In this Google's repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) you can find updated examples