# virtual environment - can import package without having it installed in my venv

Tags: python, virtual-environment

I have created a virtual environment in python in ubuntu in Raspberry Pi with:

```
python -m venv ./venv/myname
```

That gives me folderstructure:

```
   myFolder
        +-- venv
        +-- myApplication.py
```

Im activating my virtualenvironment running:

```
source venv/myname/bin/activate
```

What I dont understand is when I am running

```
python myApplication.py
```

I can run the application using python packages installed globally but not in my virtual environment. For example I can `import numpy` without having it installed in my virtual environment but globaly. I thought I needed to install everything within my virtual environment no matter if I have it globally or not. Do I misunderstand something here?

Im using python 3.7
This is my output from `print(sys.path)`

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_PCA9685-1.0.1-py3.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>>
```

**UPDATE**
The virtual environment seems to be running after all with testing it with `os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']`. Weird enough I can run packages I have not installed in my virtual environment. Here is output from my terminal:

```
(myenv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/myproject/myenv$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
'/home/pi/Desktop/myproject/myenv'
>>> exit()
(myenv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/myproject/myenv$ deactivate
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/myproject/myenv$ pythonPython 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'VIRTUAL_ENV'
>>>
```

Comment: Update your question with the results of `which python` and `import sys; print(sys.path())`

Comment: done! I updated my first post with the result

Comment: It would be useful to know the order of command you're running. Can you add a trace?

Comment: the order of command? Do you mean in which order I am performing different tasks? Besides sudo pip install virtualenv

Comment: see update in my first post

Answer (score 3):

It is very clear to me your virtual environment (venv) has not been activated (see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/determine-if-python-is-running-inside-virtualenv) for ways to verify).

You can run your programs without activating by running `./venv/myname/bin/python myApplication.py`. However, you probably don't want to be using this everytime as it's verbose.

There can be a ton of system-specific reasons why your venv isn't being activated after running `source`. My recommendation is to first reinstall virtualenv, delete  your venv, and recreate.

Comment: That seems to be correct. Verified that with checing the adress with: ````pip -V```` I reinstalled virtualenv and recreated the venv but that didnt change anything unfortunately.