# activating virtual environment not working

Tags: python, virtualenv

On my server (digitalocean droplet), when I activate my virtual environment, it seems something is not working.  I say the because:

1. It does not give me the virtual environment name inside paranthesis on the command line
2. When I run `deactivate` commend, it says `deactivate: command not found`

```
user@django-s-1vcpu-2gb-sfo3-01:~/example$source env/bin/activate
user@django-s-1vcpu-2gb-sfo3-01:~/example$
```

running `source env/bin/activate` should output the following command line:

```
(user) user@django-s-1vcpu-2gb-sfo3-01:~/example$
```

I did check which folder I am at and if the env virtual environment is shown under that folder.  I also looked at [this point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/determine-if-python-is-running-inside-virtualenv), and when I go to `python manage.py shell` and type those lines of code, it says I am not in the virtualenv! So, why is that? and how to fix it without completely mess up my live production site?

Comment: Have you checked that the activate script is in the bin folder?

Comment: yes!  I went inside the bin folder and ran ```source activate```, no difference at all

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated the virtual environment using `virtualenv env`.  I was reluctant to do so fearing making more problems with my live production site, but it looks OK so far. I will update if this solution has unintended consequences down the road.