# Python packages keep installing to local drive instead of project's virtual environment using pip from terminal

Tags: python, powershell, pip, virtualenv

currently, anytime I try to install python packages via pip commands in Visual Studio Code terminal, they are installing to my local drive instead of the virtual environment created within the project directory even when the virtual environment is activated. The virtual environment is also selected as the interpreter when referencing the lower right-hand corner of Visual Studio Code application window.

Does someone know what is causing this and how I can update this so that packages will install into the virtual environment Lib/site-packages directory instead of my local drive? I've checked multiple posts on here, but found nothing to resolve my issue. Recreating the virtual environments/upgrading pip did not do anything. I'm stuck at this point.

I tried a clean re-install of Python on my system to see if that would fix anything but the issue persists. I'm not sure why the python packages are installing to local drive instead of project virtual environment.. my best guess is that it could be something with the local drive version of pip being used for commands rather than in the venv, which is causing packages to be installed on the local drive instead?

Any help is much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: What does the `pip -V` command return after activating your environment? according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38939054/15537469

Comment: If you don't show us the exact commands you're running, how is anyone to do anything except guess? (The output of `command -v pip` or `type pip` or `which pip` depending on your shell, f/e, will tell us whether pip is coming from a virtualenv or from elsewhere; comparing it to `command -v python`, if they're from different sources, the obvious/easy answer is to use `python -m pip` instead of `pip` directly).

Comment: (...whereas if you're using an IDE instead of running commands at a shell in the first place, and can't reproduce this at a shell, ask a question _about your IDE_, tagged so people who have general Python expertise but not IDE expertise can ignore it).

Comment: @GuiEpi - after running 'pip -V', here is the output: `pip 24.0 from C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)`

So the pip on my local drive is being utilized rather than the pip within the venv.. maybe this could be causing the installation onto local rather than venv.. any way to update/correct this? Idk if its an issue with the venv activation not updating my path correctly or not, but the interpreter for VS Code is set to the venv..

My project directory is `C:\Users\marti\Documents\Coding\PythonProjects\project_name\ `

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thanks for your comment Charles.. please see my comment to GuiEpi.. pip on local drive is being used rather than venv pip.. I am running commands from the terminal (pwsh) itself.. here are the steps I'm taking as well just for additional info:

Comment: @CharlesDuffy (cont)
1. I use `python -m venv venv` command to create the virtual environment within my project directory.
2. I then run `.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat` to run the script for "activating" the virtual environment. There is no prefix in front of my cursor after executing this.
3. After attempting to install a package via `pip install [package_name]`, the system either installs it into my local drive, or if already existing, says requirement is already satisfied and lists a file path on my local drive rather than my virtual environment.

Comment: Does that change if, after the activate, you use `python -m pip install`? (On UNIX, I'd tell you to run `command -v pip` and compare it before and after you activated the virtualenv to see if the virtualenv is providing a replacement pip command at all, but I don't remember the Windows equivalent to that command; maybe it's `which` or something like that?)

Comment: BTW, is your shell cmd.exe or powershell? If it's powershell, there's a separate `activate.ps1` you want to use instead of `activate.bat`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Wow, that was the issue. I've been trying to activate the venv using the batch file each time. Using the ps1 file instead, it seems to activate successfully, displaying "(venv)" in front of the terminal cursor, and packages being installed into `venv\Scripts\site-packages` I could have sworn I've used the batch file previously with no issues... but who knows.

Thanks a lot @CharlesDuffy!

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in the title. Instead, post an answer (yes, you can [answer your own question](/help/self-answer)) or invite Charles to post an answer, then after 48 hours, you can click the checkmark to [accept it](/help/accepted-answer), which basically marks the issue as solved.

Comment: In addition to what wjandrea is saying -- make sure the question includes all the information necessary to reach the solution -- right now, some of that information is only in comments. (I'm adding an answer, but right now that answer doesn't follow from the question! -- even adding a powershell tag might suffice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activate.bat` is only compatible with cmd.exe.

When you're using PowerShell, you want to use `activate.ps1` instead -- or just invoke `activate` and let the shell select an appropriate implementation.

Comment: I think the best practice is to simply call `activate` without any ending, it should always work.

Comment: @Pux, good call, thank you; incorporating that.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as intended I think. You need to activate the virtual environment to install packages to it. You need to execute the script under `venv/Scripts/activate` (Windows and depending on your specific venv path), on Linux it's similar.

It is definitely badly designed, one alternative could be using a modern package manager such as poetry, there you don't need to activate anything. There are also bleeding edge pip replacements such as `uv`, which by default don't install packages globally.

Comment: Hm I've tried activating the environment but the packages are still saving to the local drive even when activated. Not sure if something is going wrong with the activation but I can't tell

Comment: Is there a name in parenthesis in front of your command line after activating the venv? You should see something like `(my-project-py3.12) PS C:/path/to/project>`

Comment: You don't *need* to activate it. You can run `my_venv/bin/pip` directly to install to the virtual environment `my_venv`. Activation just updates your `PATH` so that `pip` alone resolves to the virtual environment version, rather than a global version.

Comment: @Pux - No, there is no prefix in front of my cursor after activating via '.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat' command..

Comment: @chepner - sure, I will try that as an interim solution, however, I've never had this issue before and used to be able to run 'pip install [package_name]' command and system would install packages to venv successfully.. based on this and my observations, I guess there is something wrong with the venv activation as its not updating my `PATH` correctly then?

Comment: I've had similar issues where vs code was not sticking to the selected interrupter, which determines the installation directory the project is pointing to. Try shutting vs code down entirely, open the project up again, activate the venv (this should trigger a notice at the bottom of the IDE notifying you vscode detected the activation of a venv and whether you want to use it) or better yet select the interpreter through the command pallet (Command Shift P/Ctrl Shift P) the interpreters should have the installation dir beside them so you can properly identify the local venv you set up. hth!