How to dectivate virtualenv in Linux
I'm starting a new process from a Python script using subprocess. In this new process, a new virtual environment should be activated, but for some reason the old environment remains active, to deactivate the old environment, I use the deactivate call.
My script
commands = """
call deactivate
pip install -r req.txt
./venv/Scripts/activate
""".format(script_to_run)

result = subprocess.run(commands, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')

How can I achieve the same in Linux?

What's with the .format(script_to_run) method call?

It might not be a good idea to run pip inside the OS's 'canonical' Python environment. You should install distro-provided packages instead.

deactivate is an alias so you can't normally run it in a noninteractive script.
The simple solution is to explicitly run /usr/bin/pip (or /usr/local/bin/pip3 or whatever your global pip is) instead of letting the one inside the venv take precedence.
(However, I would generally advise against installing packages system-wide.)
What happens in the subprocess stays in the subprocess, so there is also no need to activate again at the end.
... Though of course, if you run additional commands in the subprocess, it might make sense to activate a specific virtual environment. You don't need to explicitly deactivate the previous one before you do that; the new one will simply replace everything which was in the old one.
commands = """
# this should show that pip without a path will
# run the one from the virtual env
command -v pip
# install system-wide, outside the current venv
/usr/bin/pip install -r req.txt
# now maybe activate a _different_ venv?
. ./another/bin/activate
# Again, this should verify that you are now
# inside the "another" venv
command -v pip
"""

result = subprocess.run(commands, shell=True, executable='/bin/sh')

Notice also that the correct syntax to activate a virtual environment is
. ./path_to_venv/bin/activate

i.e. you need the leading . and the script is in bin, not in Scripts.
Bash has source but . is portable to sh and other shells.

It might not be a good idea to run pip inside the OS's 'canonical' Python environment. You should install distro-provided packages instead.

I don't know about that. The distro-provided packages are often quite old, at least on Debian.

Huh I accidentally commented here instead of OP's question, sorry heheheh

What you did is in essence:

Start a new bash process
Deactivate the virtual env inside that bash process
End the bash process.

These changes happen only in the bash child process, though.
The parent process, the one running your Python program, doesn't change.
To change the virtual env of a currently running, Python interpreter, exec the activate_this.py file in the Scripts subdir in your virtual environment:
ACTIVATOR = "/full/path/to/the/activate_this.py"
exec(open(ACTIVATOR).read(), {"__file__": ACTIVATOR})

So, if, say, you created a virtual env in /home/roman/venv1, then ACTIVATOR should be set to /home/roman/venv1/Scripts/activate_this.py
If you need to ensure dependencies exist in the virtual env, invoke a shell script with pip before activation:
import subprocess

VENV = "venv1"

shell_commands = (
    f"python -m venv {VENV} &&"
    f"source {VENV}/activate &&"
    f"python -m pip install -r req.txt"
)
result = subprocess.run(shell_commands, shell=True)

ACTIVATOR = f"{VENV}/Scripts/activate_this.py"
exec(open(ACTIVATOR).read(), {"__file__": ACTIVATOR})


EDIT 1
Deactivating Virtual Environment for Subprocesses
You can simply do the following:

Grab current process' env vars
Reset PATH
Unset VIRTUAL_ENV
(Optionally) reset PYTHONHOME
Execute whatever you want to execute

Like this:
import os
import subprocess

new_env = os.environ.copy()
new_env["PATH"] = new_env.pop("_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH")
del new_env["VIRTUAL_ENV"]
if "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME" in new_env:
    del new_env["_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME"]

# command1 will be executed _outside_ of any virtual environments
result = subprocess.run("commmand1", env=new_env)

If you want the rest of the script to be executed outside the virtual environment
This is a bit more complex as the interpreter is already running and we need to modify some runtime values:
import os
import site
import sys

# Func taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883251/149900
def get_base_prefix_compat():
    """Get base/real prefix, or sys.prefix if there is none."""
    return (
        getattr(sys, "base_prefix", None)
        or getattr(sys, "real_prefix", None)
        or sys.prefix
    )

# Surefire way to detect if we're in a virtualenv.
# Source: Same as above func
if sys.prefix != get_base_prefix_compat():
    os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ.pop("_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH")
    del os.environ["VIRTUAL_ENV"]
    if "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME" in os.environ:
        os.environ["PYTHONHOME"] = os.environ.pop("_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME")
    # Modify list in-place
    sys.path[:] = sys.path[1:]
    sys.prefix = get_base_prefix_compat()

# .. rest of the code, including import's etc., follows ...


The OP seems to be asking how to run pip outside of any virtual environment, though? Even when you are currently inside one.

@tripleee ah, you're right. I just commented on the OP's question if that is so.
